# WCF response issue

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

[image: this is the service method implementation]

I have come across some strange problem. I have a WCF service which exposes a method to save Observablcollection of user defined object. This object has a byte[] property and it also returns the same collection to client.

When I call this method the completed event doesn't get fired and if i again call the same method it starts executing the method repeatedly until wcf timed out.

Any guess what is going wrong there ?

Thanks.

Comment: We can't guess whats wrong. Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

How large is you collection? There are chances that this is happening due to sending huge data from server to client than max limit specified by HTTP response.

Comment: I am trying with minimal data. Maximum 2-3 objects are there in the collection. Each of them are carrying  30kb file converted into byte[].

Comment: Hey, actually when you transfer data from server to client, the object gets serialize. Now I think it's not size of the collection that causing you the problem, it's probably the length of the serialized collection. Since the serialized collection is very large  it probably taking a lot of time. So just for check try sending one object at a time. Or else try to increase timeout for the service.